# Overlay css not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm putting an overlay so that the elements on my page are disabled.
On my page there are two elements.
One is an `anchor` tag and another is a `file upload` input control.
File upload control is invisible by default and is triggered on clicking the anchor tag.
The problem is i have an overlay over these controls but its not working for the invisible file upload control.
During overlay if i click on the file upload area its triggered.Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T5E8D/)
Try clicking the PR text in jsfiddle, it shouldn't work due to overlay but is clickable

Here is the html code

```
<div class="ast">
<div class="notEdit-overlay"></div>
<a id="uploadQrCode" href="#" style="cursor:pointer;">Upload QR Code</a>
P<input id="qrCodeFileUpload" type="file" class="hideQRUpload" />R
</div>
```

Jquery code

```
    $('#uploadQrCode').click(function(){
    $('#qrCodeFileUpload').click();
});
```

And here is the css

```
    .hideQRUpload
{
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
}
.notEdit-overlay
{
    width: 1080px;
    height: 99%;
    left: 0px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.ast{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using?  That works as expected for me - I can't click the link.

Comment: you are right.Try clicking the PR text.It shouldn't work ..but is working....i'm trying in Chrome

Comment: Common practice when adding your own upload link is to position the hidden file input off the page (left: -1000px, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `pointer-events: none` for your upload field – http://jsfiddle.net/T5E8D/2/

Answer (score 4):

Change css for .notEdit-overlay like this

```
.notEdit-overlay
{
 width: 1080px;
 height: 99%;
 left: 0px;
 background: none;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 z-index: 1;
}
```

should use z-index.

http://jsfiddle.net/T5E8D/3/